# Ask user and print a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a problem with printing a list. 
For example I have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

Now I want to ask user to input a list name and then print that list.

```
name = input("Write a list name")
```

User entered `"a"`

```
for x in name:
    print(x)
```

But it does not work (not printing list "a"). Could You help me?

**MORE INFO:**

I have a dictionary:

```
poland = {"poznan": 86470,
          "warszawa": 86484,
          "sopot": 95266}
```

And lists:

```
poznan = [1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]

warszawa = [1503333, 93311, 93181, 93268, 106958, 106956, 127649, 106801, 107386, 93245, 154078, 107032]

sopot = [228481, 164126, 922891]
```

And now if user write "poznan" i want to assign ID of poznan from dictionary to variable "city_id" and then print a list with name "poznan"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to map the lists to strings, which are what the user can enter.

So use a dictionary:

```
lists_dict = {
    'a': [1,2,3,4,5]
    'b': [6,7,8,9,10]
}

key = input("Write a list name")

print lists_dict[key]
```

### Edit:

Your dictionary should look as follows:

```
poland = {
    "poznan": {"name": 86470, "lst": [1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]},
    "warszawa": {"name": 86484, "lst": [1503333, 93311, 93181, 93268, 106958, 106956, 127649, 106801, 107386, 93245, 154078, 107032]},
    "sopot": {"name": 95266, "lst": [228481, 164126, 922891]}
}
```

Access to your list should be done like so:

```
key = input("Write a list name")
# print the list under 'lst' for the dictionary under 'key'
# print poland[key]["lst"]
# EDIT: python 3's print a function, thanks @Ffisegydd:
print(poland[key]["lst"])
```

Comment: Is it the only way? I can not use dictionary in this case because i have other code which will not work with it.

Comment: This, to my world view, is the *right* way, see other answers for other ways. :) Show a more loyal example of the code and maybe we can fix it.

Comment: Ok here is more info:
I have a dictionary with "name" and "id" values. 
I am asking user for "name" and then i print "id" from this dictionary. I want also to print a list which name is "name" from this dictionary. I hope You understand what i mean.

Comment: Add an example of the dictionary to your question. This is easily fixable.

Comment: The idea of "naming" variables is difficult. If I say `a = 1` and then say `b = a`, is my integer named `a` or `b`? This is why you should use a dictionary as Reut has suggested.

Comment: More code:

    `poland = {"poznan": 86470,
          "warszawa": 86484,
          "sopot": 95266}`

And lists:

    `poznan = [1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]

    warszawa = [1503333, 93311, 93181, 93268, 106958, 106956, 127649, 106801, 107386, 93245, 154078, 107032]

    sopot = [228481, 164126, 922891]`

Comment: Add this to your question on top, not here in the comments. If this is what you have include the lists in the mapping under a certain key. You can re-map a list of dictionaries to any key using the code I posted in the edit.

Comment: Ok i updated first post. I hope now it is easy to understand.

Comment: @ReutSharabani thank You so much for update. Of course i can use for loop to print all "lst" right?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `globals()` dictionary like this  `print(globals()[name])`. `input()` returns a single name, so there is no need to use loop either.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> name = input("Write a list name ")
Write a list name a
>>> globals()[name]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

After OP's edit:

```
>>> poland = {"poznan": 86470,
...           "warszawa": 86484,
...           "sopot": 95266}
>>> poznan = [1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]
>>> warszawa = [1503333, 93311, 93181, 93268, 106958, 106956, 127649, 106801, 107386, 93245, 154078, 107032]
>>> sopot = [228481, 164126, 922891]
>>> name = input("Enter name: ")
Enter name: poznan
>>> city_id = poland[name]
>>> city_id
86470
>>> globals()[name]
[1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]
>>>
```

Comment: giving `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @AerofoilKite, you didn't enter quote around `a`. That's why getting the error. Please check the edit. OP clearly said that use entered `"a"` with quote.

Comment: how did you mange to use `print globals()[name]` in a python3 shell?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm using 2.x but I guess that's a minor change that everyone can figure out. Anyway, I'm fixing that too.

Comment: well input in python2 is very different to input in python3 that is why  Aerofil got the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, you will get `unhashable type` error in 2.x too if you don't use quote.

Comment: @taskinoor, yes but the OP is using python 3 so  entering `"a"` will throw a keyerror there.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks for pointing that. I will have a look into this again when I get chance to check with 3.x.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, edited the answer to work with 3.x. Thanks again for pointing this. I completely missed this while writing the answer.

Comment: @taskinoor, no worries